# How do I find the line number in my logcat?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I've been getting a persistent erro and this time I can not find the problem. Some people state that logcat will show the problamatic line number, however, I have yet to find to this awesome resource.
This is the logcat that shows the error I get as the app crashes when I pull out the keyboard.

```
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at com.daniel.kilometermilecoverter.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:171)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:2956)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3049)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1015)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3740)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547): [FRANDRO_ERR_HANDLER] com_android_internal_os_RuntimeInit_BlueErrorHandler
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at com.daniel.kilometermilecoverter.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:171)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:2956)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3049)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1015)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3740)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 10:04:44.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29547): [FRANDRO_ERR_HANDLER] Done.
```

Comment: line numbers are usually identified in exception's **StackTrace**

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers at the end of the end of the lines (in the parenthesis with the file names) are the line number upon which the error occurred. Find the files that deal with your program and look at the corresponding line number initcated (In this case MainActivity.java line 171).

Answer (score 1):

Write .java in logcat searchbar you can see this line

com.daniel.kilometermilecoverter.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:171) 06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547): at

Answer (score 0):

com.daniel.kilometermilecoverter.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(***MainActivity.java:171***) 06-14 10:04:42.734: E/AndroidRuntime(29547): at

Answer (score 0):

Here's you activity and the line.

com.daniel.kilometermilecoverter.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:171) 06-14 10:04:42.744: E/AndroidRuntime(29547):